# Different results from JSON data when retrieved in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to retrieve some data from an API in my react app. When I view the endpoint in FireFox there is an value `_embedded`, which is what I need, but when I access that endpoint in the react app, it is not there:

**Firefox, viewing /wp-json/wp/v2/product?per_page=100&_embed :**

[image]

**When i view the endpoint via console.log in Inspector, viewing /wp/v2/product?per_page=100&_embed :**

[image]

Is there something that I am missing?

**Update:**

I am using the following in React:

```
const Component = ({ state, actions }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(state.source.api + "/wp/v2/product?per_page=100&_embed")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setProducts(data);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Show us how you are making that request in react.

Comment: And what _exactly_ did you log to console now, when you say you “viewed the endpoint” in there?

Comment: console.log(products);

Comment: You should first of all check what `response` actually contained. That way, you will be able to tell whether this was actually a problem with the request itself - or if your processing of the data afterwards was faulty.